# How to save a trunckated svd model in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, pca, svd, truncated

I am working on a machine learning project. I have applied truncated svd on my data for feature reduction and then trained the neural networks on that data. I have saved the neural network model using to_json(). How can I save the truncated svd model for transforming unseen  data later.

Here is how I have used truncated svd.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
model = TruncatedSVD(n_components=600,n_iter=10).fit(train_features)
train_features= model.transform(train_features)
test_features= model.transform(test_features)`
```

I hope that I made this question clear.  Can someone assist me in solving this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python pickle library

```
import pickle
# To save
pickle.dump(model, "model.p")
# To load again
with open('model.p', 'r') as fp:
    model = pickle.load(fp)
```

Comment: We need to create a file object for this to work:
`file_obj = open("model.p", "wb") ; 
pickle.dump(model, file_obj)`